# SP2007 (All)UserData nvarchar field content garbled for choice fields

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007, sql-server, content-database, choice-field

In our SharePoint 2007, one of our lists field is configured as such:

```
<Field Type="Choice" DisplayName="Standard" Required="FALSE" Format="RadioButtons" FillInChoice="FALSE" Group="gc_xyz" ID="{e5d39160-a777-4d70-b372-a7ca76305adc}" SourceID="{21f217b9-cbc5-44b8-96b7-2c665aecc37f}" StaticName="Standard" Name="Standard" ColName="nvarchar20" RowOrdinal="0">
    <CHOICES>
        <CHOICE>Yes</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>No</CHOICE>
    </CHOICES>
</Field>
```

But when I look in the AllUserData table (or its view), the data for this field is like this:

| nvarchar20 |
| --- |
| 챂䗅⎑啄獌崿 |
| ំ싖줚䎭권䞢⋫ |
| 嫎⚔潣俎즤떴ಇ긅 |
| စ꼨噡䊔ꆫ䐂㪗⋉ |
| ᶷ刊ᯉ䯥梋蓊㯕Ꙃ |
| 㩝䪿撾럌阶紻 |
| ពု帵䙏熦༱䏇䶌 |
| 왜汵䅩粁ʹ猅 |

All values are different, as if hashed. How do I read those values to translate them to Yes/No?

Comment: You should never access SharePoint databases directly. What are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: We are decommissionning the server, and the Sharepoint app was heavily customized a long time ago, to a point where it's not practically feasible to upgrade it to another version. The decision was made to replace it with a new app, but we need to export the data into a new Database. Data will be normalized and simplified.

Comment: You'll want to export through supported SharePoint APIs, or for a List, even use Export to Excel or Open with Access.